# Material Dialogs import issue

Tags: android, dialog

How does one use the afollestad/material-dialogs on github in Android Java?

His codes are all available in Kotlin. I can run the project via Android studio, but my project is in Java. I've been able to implement the file in my project.

But I can't seem to get a hang of the code. After a couple of hours of searching, I think I'm about to give up except for this last shot.

Any help?

Comment: Same problem here. Do you get any solution?

Comment: I asked the developers and they said that it cannot be used with Android Java